# SQL View / Function /with Variable in Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

following is my SQL Query. It contains variable so i guess it cannot be save as VIEW. How can i make it work with Function / Stored Procedure / View?

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max);

SELECT @sql = Coalesce(@sql + ' UNION ALL ', '') + 
'SELECT *  FROM ' + QuoteName(DatabaseName) + '.dbo.states'

FROM   sanketuniversal.dbo.databasemaster
where itemdata = 0 and CustomerGroupfordisplay = 1;


--PRINT @sql
EXEC (@sql);
```

Another option is Function. I also tried but getting an error.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MNReport()
RETURNS @MN_table TABLE (
    SIDs VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    StateName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    )
    AS
BEGIN   

DECLARE @sql varchar(max);
     INSERT INTO @MN_table



SELECT @sql = Coalesce(@sql + ' UNION ALL ', '') + 

        'SELECT count(*)  FROM ' + QuoteName(DatabaseName) + '.dbo.states' 

FROM   sanketuniversal.dbo.databasemaster
where itemdata = 0 and CustomerGroupfordisplay = 1;


      RETURN;
END;
```

**Error: "An INSERT statement cannot contain a SELECT statement that assigns values to a variable "**

Comment: Should work as a procedure.

Comment: Are you going to have varying number of databases? Why are you using dynamic code? You could rebuild your view/function every time a database is added or removed. Or you could simply forget about having many identical databases and use a column in your tables.

Comment: Your question is unclear but it appears you want to write some logic that will iterate through some set of databases and run the same query against each, combining the results into a single resultset. So - go [search the internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+run+query+on+all+databases&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS727US727&oq=sql+server+run+query+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l4j69i60l2.6156j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Nope - you cannot use a function (without hardcoding the databases) and you cannot use a view.

Comment: @LuisCazares, yes i am using dynamic code because do not want to edit query every time when new database is added. Also cannot combine databases into one as these are very large and complex.

Comment: @SMor, goal is I do not want to edit Query every time when database is added. So this is dynamic query.